# Singleton + initialization code

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, singleton

I have a singleton that is initialized like all singletons, with something like this:

```
+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance
{
  static MySingleton *sharedMyInstance = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyInstance = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
  });
  return sharedMyInstance;

}
```

In my case I want to add some code to initialize the singleton but because sharedInstance is a class method I cannot call instance methods from there.

So I always have to have this pattern:

```
MySingleton *sing = [MySingleton sharedInstance];
[sing initialize];
```

Ok, I can do this

```
MySingleton *sing = [[MySingleton sharedInstance] initialize];
```

but this will generate another problem because if initializing the singleton is the only thing I want at this point, `sing` is not being used and this is ugly code.

I suppose I can do simply

```
[[MySingleton sharedInstance] initialize];
```

and Xcode will not complain, but this does not sound good.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your code ;-) Specifically the line:

```
sharedMyInstance = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
```

You have to implement `init` and there is where you'll initialize the instance variables of your singleton (AKA shared instance). It will be called the first time the shared instance is used.

Comment: Sorry about that. I must be really tired... :)